# How to setup auto archiving on Outlook with multiple email accounts to multiple archives?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, archiving

Currently this is about Outlook 2010 but I am willing to update Outlook if this is easier in a newer version.

I have multiple PCs which receive multiple email accounts in Outlook. I like to have email account A auto-archived in archive A, email account B auto-archived into archive B, etc.
And I like to be able to set these settings for folders including subfolders. I.e. do auto-archive of all Sent-Items and subfolder of Sent-Items. Don't do archiving for the Inbox and any subfolders in the inbox. And this maybe different for individual email accounts.

Currently I see only the possibility to set these settings individually to each folder which is a lot of work. Is there an easy way to do this?
If there is no easy build in way to do this I am willing to run macros and/or write my own VBA if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [Set Folder AutoArchive Settings](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderAutoArchive/) utility to configure multiple selected folders at once, including subfolders, etc. Just select required folders, set options and run the tool. Please note that I recommend this program because I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As far as I see your utility has lots of functions but not really what I want and need.

Comment: Why? It looks like it does exactly what you want: sets configured permissions for multiple folders at once.